# Neo4j Inheritance - ArgumentError: comparison of Class with Class failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, cypher

I have Email models that inherit

```
class Email
   def self.email_types
       {
         welcome_email: EmailWelcome,
         ban_email: EmailBan
       }
    end

    def self.create_new(params)
       klass = Object.const_get(params[:type].to_s)
       klass.new(params)
    end
end

class EmailBan < Email
end

class EmailWelcome < Email
end
```

The `Email` class is abstract. The classes are created via `Email.create_new` with a type that matches a concrete class.

If I type `Email.count` It will count all `EmailWelcome` and `EmailBan`. This is what I want, so I can list all Emails via `Email.all`.

But sometimes when trying to iterate or call `Email.first` I get the following error.

```
irb(main):138:0> Email.last
ArgumentError: comparison of Class with Class failed
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-4.1.5/lib/neo4j/active_node/node_wrapper.rb:34:in `sort'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-4.1.5/lib/neo4j/active_node/node_wrapper.rb:34:in `sorted_wrapper_classes'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-4.1.5/lib/neo4j/active_node/node_wrapper.rb:7:in `wrapper'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:86:in `hash_value_as_object'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:68:in `map_row_value'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in to_node_enumeration'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:57:in `each_pair'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:57:in `each_with_object'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in to_node_enumeration'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:43:in `block in each'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:140:in `block in each_data_row'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:140:in `each'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:140:in `each_data_row'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:55:in `block in to_node_enumeration'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-core/query.rb:176:in `each'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-core/query.rb:176:in `each'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-core/query.rb:176:in `each'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-core/query.rb:212:in `map'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-core/query.rb:212:in `pluck'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-4.1.5/lib/neo4j/active_node/query_methods.rb:20:in `last'
    from (irb):138
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/perich/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Comment: Before digging into this, could you try it with version 5.2.x of the `neo4j` gem (at the moment the newest version is 5.2.14)

Comment: @BrianUnderwood I'll give that a try. I think it has to do with Ruby trying to force a collection of different classes into some order. ```["1", 1].sort``` gives a similar error. I did add a ```<=>``` method, but no luck.

Comment: My instinct was that it has to do with an issue that we (I think) fixed a while back where model classes were getting reloaded but the old class was still around and there were objects from the old class still around (perhaps being compared to objects of the new class)

Comment: @PeterR did you find the solution to this issue?